# AWS Personalize — algorithmHyperParameters must be an associative array. Found array

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

According to documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-personalize-2018-05-22.html#createsolution), when you create solution, you must provide `algorithmHyperParameters` as array of strings, so I did:

```php
'solutionConfig' => [
    'algorithmHyperParameters' => [
        'min_copurchase_count',
        'exponentiation_parameter',
    ],
    ...
],
```

But script fails with error:

```sh
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the CreateSolution operation:
[solutionConfig][algorithmHyperParameters] must be an associative array. Found array(2) in /var/www/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Validator.php:65
```

How `algorithmHyperParameters` can be `an associative array` in this case? I have tried to make it as associative array, but I have not found any valid.

Can someone help to figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in this documentation, because in other documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_CreateSolution.html) this parameter is:

1. Does not required.
2. If you need it, it should be like:

```php
'solutionConfig' => [
    'algorithmHyperParameters' => [
        '<string>' => '<string>',
    ],
    ...
],
```